# Executing an import statement string and using the import

Tags: python, string

Currently, I have a line of code such as `import module`.

Instead, how can I do something like `run_python("import module")`?

Please keep in mind that I would like to use the module in my script after importing it.

Comment: ```exec("import module")```? or ```eval("import module")```

Comment: Is your intention to import a module by a name dynamically generated?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `importlib` module, not "executing python code as a string"

Comment: `import ast`
`code = "print('hello')"`
`block = ast.parse(code, mode='exec')`
`exec(compile(block, '<string>', mode='exec'))`